# How can I register a table from an external source with a geodatabase so that I can create relationship classes?

Tags: arcgis-server, esri-geodatabase, relationship-class, arcgis-portal

I have two databases. The first is an enterprise geodatabase. The second is a SQL Server database that I have read only permissions to on another server. I am using ArcMap and ArcServer 10.4.1.

I am able to establish database connections to both database servers and create relates and joins without issue.

My goal is to use relationship classes with data I publish to services that will end up in ArcGIS portal. I know I have to use relationship classes since joins and relates won't work with portal.

I was under the impression that I could register tables from my external database with my geodatabase with the "Registerwithgeodatabase" tool. Then, I planned on creating my relationship classes.

When I run the tool I get "001400 : Only the data owner may execute register with geodatabase". Since there is only one input, it seems as though the tool may be trying to register the table from my external database with a non-existent geodatabase on the same server.

What am I doing wrong here and how can I register an external database table where I have readonly permissions with my geodatabase so that I can create relationship classes?

Edit: My external database contains only non-spacial data.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Question and Answer format. *Register with Geodatabase* does not work like that.  Register with Geodatabase adds ObjectID to a table already in the geodatabase, and adds to the geodatabase register, so that it is able to be used by ArcGIS.  It does not link a table in a non-geodatabase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RegisterWithGeodatabase_management` requires an enterprise geodatabase, and only applies to *tables* in the connection's database, which are owned by the same-named schema of the connected user. It is hyperinefficient to join across connections. Instead look for a replication procedure to push the table to the enabled instance.